# Cannot read property 'run' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, mandrill

I'm trying to use Parse Cloud Code to send a transactional email with Mandrill. I keep getting the following error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined

I've been working on this little piece of code and cannot seem to understand what is wrong. What's wrong with my code?

```
email.save(null, {
        success: function(email) {
            console.log('New object created with objectId: ' + email.id);
            Parse.Cloud.run('introEmail', {
                Address: $(".form-control").val()
                }, {
                success: function(results) {
                    response.success(results);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    response.error("Some error.");              
            };      
        },
        error: function(email, error) {
            alert('Could not accept email address: ' + error.message);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: It means `Parse.Cloud` evaluates to `undefined`.

Comment: Do you include Parse lib in your project?

Comment: @farhatmihalko Yes, I did. All functions that use Parse work correctly except for this single function where I am using Cloud Code.

Answer (score 0):

Update the parse sdk head in the head of the html to support Parse Cloud Code. The current Javascript sdk is 1.2.19.

```
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.19.min.js"></script>
```